# Railscasts #37 undefined method 'each' for nil:nilclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the video on Railcasts but I'm stuck. Here is my code:

locals_controller.rb

```
def landing
@locals = Local.search(params[:search])
end
```

local.rb (model)

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('nome LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

and the view landing.html.erb

```
<% if signed_in? %>
<%= form_tag root_path, :method => :get, :class  => "center form-search" do %>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class  =>  "input-medium search-query" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class  => "btn" %>
    </p>
    <%= render "landing_search" %>
<% end %>
```

and the partial that has raised the error, because, basically, `@locals` is nil because it says `"undefined method each for nil:nilClass"`:

```
_landing_search.html.erb

    <% @locals.each do |local| %>
    ...
```

What did I miss?

I'va also added

```
match '/', to: "locals#landing"
```

in my `routes.rb` because, in my case, the page to be displayed is in the root path

Comment: Do you have any other errors in the log? `where` and `all` shouldn't return `nil`

Comment: the server log:
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 63ms
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    21:   </thead>
    22:
    23:   <tbody>
    24:         <% @locals.each do |local| %>
    25:           <tr>
    26:                 <td><%= link_to local.nome, local_path(local) %></td>
    27:
  app/views/locals/_landing_search.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_locals__landing_search_html_erb___218086886_50854560'
  app/views/locals/landing.html.erb:10:in `block in _app_views_locals_landing_html_erb__826246363_33903264'
  app/views/locals/landing.html.erb:2:in

Comment: what is the value of @locals in controller after search?

Comment: What do you mean? it should be @locals=Local.where( nome: "%#{search}%") i think but now is nil and i don't know why. Are model and controller correct?

Comment: I mean debug the value of `@locals` you get after `@locals = Local.search(params[:search])` is it nil there itself or is it being getting manipulated elsewhere in middle.

Comment: what i have to do to see it? search should be a method defined in local controller and it should be not nil.

Comment: In the controller add `Rails.logger.debug "LOCALS: #{@locals.inspect}"` to see if it's getting anything back from the call to `Local.search`

Comment: i added it on landing action in locals controller, and now where i should see something?

Comment: if i totally remove the search method in my model the error is still the same, shouldn't change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems fine, but I've checked your code and u define the `landing` action twice (the bottom one overwrites the 1st one):

```
def landing
  @locals = Local.search(params[:search])
end

# ...    

def landing #line 86
end
```

Therefore if you delete the 2nd one everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should change **o** to **a** in name ?

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Comment: in model i have an attribute called "nome" which is the italian for "name"

Comment: @Said Kaldybaev, I think it should have thrown `mysql unknown column error` if the column name was wrong. This one runs means there is nothing wrong with column name.

Comment: anyway i tried to change the 'o' with 'a' but the error is still the same, isn't strange?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, check what you define the method of landing in controller more than one, if yes the lastest method would be called.

and the second, change your controller like this:

```
def self.search(opts)
  return self.all if opts.blank?
  self.where('nome LIKE ?', "%#{opts}%")
end
```